# How do I recharge a battery using a small solar cell

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, solar-cell, low-power, charging

I need to partially recharge a 3.7V, 2.7Wh battery. The Solar cell's output is roughly 1V with a current of 1-2 micro-Amps. I don't know hot to construct this circuit. I figure I need to use a diode, but other than that I am quite lost. What should I do?
I am mainly looking for a way to store the energy. It doesn't have to be the battery mentioned above, but the solar cell's output can't be altered due to the lighting conditions.

Comment: Get a much larger solar cell - 1 uAmp @ 1 Volt won't be enough to do anything to a 2.7 Wh cell.

Comment: 1 micro amp is below the minimum Iin required for the circuits that you would use to charge a battery form a solar cell.  The circuit used to do that is called an MPPT Max Power Point Tracking charger.  You need a charger to charge a Li-ion battery.  A power source and diode will not do the job. To be done right some intelligence  in the form of a micro controller would be required.  At a minimum a buck controller with a voltage cutoff setting.

Comment: Are you sure about those figures for your solar cell? You can pick up a 30mm square solar cell on eBay for 6p that produces 90mW, which is 45,000 times as much as yours.

Comment: Forget it altogether, or get a more suitable solar cell.

Answer (score 3):

Your solar cell, assuming the larger value of 2 microamps, can provide a power of 1 volt X 2 microamps = 2 microwatts. To provide enough energy to recharge a 2.7 Wh battery would take a minimum of 1.35 million hours (not even allowing for less than 100% efficiency in getting the solar cell energy into the battery). It should be clear that you need to get a much larger solar cell to accomplish your purpose.